# Defining Inbound and Oubound Policies in Windows Firewall,AV Firewall

Tags: windows-10, firewall, network-shares, tcpip, ports

In Windows Firewall we define Inbound & Outbound Policies for Web, Network, etc. access as we have separate settings for the same...The same if taken in an AV Firewall for example in Quick Heal Internet Security, policies get defined based on Local & Remote ports which then defines them as inbound and outbound policies. I have gone thru their settings which get stated as:....

> Inbound-- Local Ports: 139,445,80,443 etc <---- Remote Ports: Any
>
> Outbound -- Local Ports : Any --------> Remote Ports: 139,445,80,443

On certain Websites its argued as remote ports being on the client side are those that could be any random ones as the remote client would define but certain AV Firewalls define it differently as for e.g. above. So what could be the difference when it comes to AV Firewalls..and is it possible in these AV firewalls to define one policy for Inbound, Outbound (localPort: 139,445,80,443 ---- RemotePort 139,445,80,443)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On certain Websites its argued as remote ports being on the client side are those that could be any random ones as the remote client would define but certain AV Firewalls define it differently as for e.g. above

No, it's not different at all. Those rules have two different purposes – the first is for incoming connections from a remote client to a local server; the second for connections from a local client to a remote server.

In general, ports on the *client* (initiator) side are randomly chosen, while ports on the *server* (responder) side are predefined. It doesn't matter which side is "local" and which side is "remote".

> is it possible in these AV firewalls to define one policy for Inbound, Outbound (localPort: 139,445,80,443 ---- RemotePort 139,445,80,443)

No, such a rule would not match any connections. It is *extremely* rare for TCP-based protocols to deliberately use the same port on both the local and remote ends of the same connection.

Comment: `In general, ports on the client (initiator) side are randomly chosen, while ports on the server (responder) side are predefined. It doesn't matter which side is "local" and which side is "remote". `

Comment: Yes? Do you have a question about that?

Comment: Yes editing it actually.. adding to it...>
By this I would understand that if my server having an inbound policy would only matter to my client computer like say a LAN Pc requesting data from a network share on my server, the same server having an outbound policy would mean my server is like a client PC requesting data from a webserver like Google or a media server whether locally or globally....

Comment: Yes, when you connect _to_ Google via HTTPS (for example), only `local :any --> remote :443` would apply (and technically also `<-- remote :443` for reply packets, but most software firewalls are *stateful* and implicitly allow replies without the need for an explicit rule). On the other hand, if you were to _host_ a website, then `local :443 <-- remote :any` would apply.

Comment: Ok..Thanks very much..